# How to deal with a boss who doesn't listen to you and keeps criticizing?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, manager

So, I have this CTO with 15+ years of experience in my small Software Development company, who is quite knowledgeable but is extremely proud of himself over his knowledge. Although he is good in terms of giving opportunities to youngsters like me who are 1+ year experienced, but in terms of treating the employees, I find his behaviour as one of the worst I have ever seen.

He told me once that he believes in criticizing the youngsters because according to him, criticism is a best way to improve the youngsters in today's world. And according to this habit, he has zero sense of moral etiquettes on how to treat his employees. Moreover, his expectations from his employees are not even realistic but resides in some imaginary level. As he often use to say this to every young employees like me that when he was of my age, he used to commit no mistakes in programming and the QA team were used to get tired for finding even a single bug in his code. He expects that I am not a human being but a god of programming who will not commit even a single mistake in code.

Now, all that I have specified above is bearable for me. But what seems disgusting to me is when according to him, I commit some mistake and he just starts shouting like a hulk and scolds me in front of everyone and that moron, even doesn't listen to what I say to him at those times. Whenever I speak to express my point of views, then he suppress my voice by speaking in a shouting manner and I generally stay silent in these kind of situations as  it seems to me that arguing with such kind of people is a wastage of time and energy. I think that one of the biggest reason for me to get scolded every time is because I generally speak 100% truth and am completely honest in front of him. Now, there is another colleague of mine, who is a very religious person in the eyes of everyone but he is an extremely cunning dude. Whenever he faces situation like mine in front of our CTO, he puts the blame of his mistake on others or just simply lie to him and gets lucky to not get a scolding from the CTO because of getting saved every time by making fool of him.

*Now, how should I deal with this boss? Should I start behaving in a cunning manner as my colleague?* I have talked to the CTO regarding this fact that I think that I am getting too much scolded more than what is required and it sometimes have a bad affect on my mental peace and this continuous criticism has also lowered my confidence to some extent but talking to him brought no significant results. Another way I see is to just bear him for 10 months more because as a fresher, I had signed a bond of 2 years with my company and it has been 1 year 2 months since my joining.

*Can someone please suggest a good solution for this situation?*

Comment: I fear that Joe is right... this seems no good place to be in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are lessons to be learned here**.

First of all, promise yourself that you'll never behave like this CTO.  Shouting is not an effective way to motivate people to succeed in a job that requires care and concentration.

Second, learn what to communicate, and when.

> I generally speak 100% truth and am completely honest in front of him

Never lie, but it is fair for you to pick and choose which details are necessary for the CTO to hear and which are not.

Pay attention to what you say that triggers a shouting episode.

If you're successful, you'll gain a very useful skill (knowing what to say, when to say it, and how much to say).

Please note that lying and blaming others is not a satisfactory long term solution.  Your colleague will eventually discover he has no friends at work and no support.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I agree about the new job, but the OP mentioned a 10 month balance on a 2 year bond.  I suspect that may limit the job search options.

Comment: Yes @Dan, that's why because of the 2 years bond, I said that I have to bear him for 10 months more.

Answer (score 3):

> Now, how should I deal with this boss? Should I start behaving in a cunning manner as my colleague?

I am afraid to say that this does not read like an inspiring or positive boss. The fact that he even made you consider lying and acting "cunningly" is proof that this does not bring the good side on their employees.

In fact, this seems to me like a **toxic boss** to have, and if things are like you describe it also not the kind of environment I would want to work in.

Not frequently I suggest this, but I fear that **you should be considering finding a new job**, one where hopefully you don't have a boss like this.

Start jub-hunting ASAP, keep doing your job the best you can and try to avoid confrontation in the meanwhile. The moment you land an offer, give your notice, serve it, and move on from this negative experience you had.